# is ADD-distributiongroupmember a cmdlet in powershell to add members into a distribution list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a powershell script to add and remove members from a distribution list which is present in the active directory.I tried a command for adding members to the distribution list which is like:
ADD-DistributionGroupmember -identity "staff" -member "johnevans@contoso.com"
but when i try to execute this command i get an error saying that add-distributiongroupmember is an invalid command.
so,can anyone provide me a powershell script to add and remove members from the distribution list which is present in the active directory.

Answer (score 1):

Add-DistributionGroupMember is an Exchange cmdlet, and requires the Exchange management snapin, or a remote Exchange management session.

You can accomplish the same thing using the ActiveDirectory module and Add-ADGroupMember, but you won't be able to use the user's email address as the member identity to add. Exchange will work with that as an identity reference, but the native AD cmdlets won't.

Comment: Use Add-ADGroupMember as mjolinor stated, the Exchange cmdlets are unnecessary for adding and removing users from groups, it's not an exchange related activity.

Comment: It's not necessary, but if all they're giving him is the email address it may be a lot more efficient.  That's not an indexed attribute in AD, and if that's all you've got you first have to search AD for the user with that address and get an identity reference (e.g. SID, UPN, sAMAccontname, or DN) that you can use with the AD module cmdlets.

Comment: Very true, however, I've seen many AD installations where the DNS domain name is the same as the email address domain, or where alias are used so that people's UPNs are the same as their email address. In those cases it would work anyway. I assume from the original question that they are not writing some piece of commercial software.

Comment: That's true, but that relies on adhering to an arbitrary naming convention.  I've seen many times a solution that relies on that appears to work with test data, then starts failing intermittently in production as it encounters instances where somebody deviated from the standard.

Comment: You are right, but I assumed that since they are writing powershell script to automate admin processes, it would be them that set the standards. Either way, I agree, it's best to do it properly. Seems odd that they would only have access to a users e-mail address though and not a name or sam.

Answer (score 0):

You need Exchange Powershell module: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/01/23/learn-how-to-use-powershell-to-run-exchange-server-commands-remotely.aspx

Comment: I am working on active directory module for windows powershell editor.

Comment: I am already working on active direcory module for window powershell editor.

Comment: Amended the link, you need to import Exchange module/snapin or set a session to your exchange box.

Comment: even now iam unable to use those commands. please provide other way to do this

Comment: If you can't run the cmdlets it is because you haven't imported the Exchange snapin or the Exchange session. Keep working through the guide and you will be able to get there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without the Exchange cmdlets, this works I tested it:

```
$groupIdentity = "My Group"
$userEmailAddress = "johnevans@contoso.com"

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupIdentity -Member (Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $userEmailAddress})
```